# Adding HTML body attributes to a React App?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am very new to React and am trying to convert a pre-made HTML site into a React App. I have converted the vast majority of the functionality over just fine, however I am trying to get the nav-bar to work as it does in the original HTML, but cannot.

Here is the original HTML for the nav-bar functionality:

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#pb-navbar" data-offset="200">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg site-navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="pb-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample09" aria-controls="navbarsExample09" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExample09">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#section-home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#section-portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#section-resume">Resume</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#section-about">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#section-contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

And here is my nav-bar React component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class TopNavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg site-navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="pb-navbar">
        <div className="container">
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample09" aria-controls="navbarsExample09" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExample09">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#section-home">Home</a></li>
              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#section-resume">Resume</a></li>
              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#section-about">About</a></li>
              <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href="#section-contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the React App.js file:

```js
import './App.css';
import TopNavBar from './components/Topnavbar';
import Introduction from './components/Introduction';
import Resume from './components/Resume';
import About from './components/About';
import Services from './components/Services';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div id="colorlib-page">
      <div id="container-wrap">
        <TopNavBar></TopNavBar>
        <div id="colorlib-main">
          <Introduction></Introduction>
          <Services></Services>
          <Resume></Resume>
          <About></About>
          <Contact></Contact>
          <Footer></Footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am pretty sure the functionality that is missing is due to the `<body>` tag's attributes being: `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#pb-navbar" data-offset="200"`, however I am not sure how to add this to the overall React app.

It also seems to be missing the CSS effects on the nav-bar, as it does not smoothly scroll when one clicks on a nav-link, but instead instantly takes you to the location.

Any direction on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused, where is the body tag you're adding your React app into? Can't you just add it there?

Comment: Hard to give you an accurate answer when we don't know your CSS.

Comment: What do you mean by "_can't make the navbar work_"? Later you say that the navbar doesn't style according to your CSS file, from which I presume you see it on the page. What _is_ the functionality you are missing? Do you see any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your React application there is a `<body>` element.  It's unlikely to be in the `<App>` component, but likely to be in whatever *uses* the `<App>` component.

For example, you may have an `index.html` which has an otherwise empty but complete/valid HTML document structure that may contain a single `<div>` in the body, and the React app is initialized in that `<div>`.

The `<body>` element in that file is the `<body>` element used in the resulting application.  That's where you can make those changes.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I actually did already try to do that. In my `public/assets/index.html` file I found the `<body>` tag and changed it to `<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#pb-navbar" data-offset="200">` and I didn't see any change. Could this be a problem with how the CSS animations are also not being shown?

Comment: @PaulGildehaus: *"and I didn't see any change"* - When you saved your changes and re-built/re-ran the application and opened it in a browser, did you open your browser's development/debugging tools and examine the DOM for the page?  Were the expected changes in the `<body>` tag?  If not then it sounds like there's some other problem going on that's invalidating the test.

Comment: Fair point, I do see now that the body attributes have been added to the body in the DOM, so I guess that was not my problem. Thanks for your help. I'll try making a new question.